# Extract data from charts in a doc file

Tags: java, ms-word, extract

I have been working on a project which requires extracting of data of a chart i.e. the X and Y values of a given chart from a doc file using Java, can you suggest something?

Comment: you mean .doc files made with word? - try POI http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: *"..using java, can u suggest something?"* I'll suggest 2 things. 1) It is 'Java' not 'java' - use correct capitals 2) Type **all 3** letters of words like 'you'.

Answer (score 0):

-if you your file is structured file like an XML file you can use java XML parsers and here is a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/TOC.html)
-if it is JSON file use java JSON parsers. 
-if your file is not structured you need to read your file using [java chars I/O library](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html) 
and parse it to get the values you want.

check this [project](https://github.com/Adio183/adelin_clouway_course/tree/xml/src/com/clouway/xml) i have made, to see how i parse a structured XML file with sax parser and using the DOM parser.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply, do you have any idea,  whether this can be done by using  apache POI libraries for word 2003 charts?